# ExtJS Dynamically setting tab index

Tags: extjs

How can I dynamically set a tab index in ExtJS?  I can't see anything in the docs for it, only a config option for it.  If I try to do an .apply, it still doesn't work.  I know I can probably extend the framework to support this since it is just a DOM element, but I'm sure I'm missing something simpler.  Help?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in the extjs code for field they do this:

```
this.el.dom.setAttribute('tabIndex', this.tabIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the set method of the Element class which you can retrieve using the get method, so something like this: `Ext.get('YOURELEMENTID').set({tabIndex:5});`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include buttons in the tabindex, i'm afraid they have to be addressed seperatley:

```
this.btnEl.dom.setAttribute('tabIndex', this.tabIndex);
```

Answer (score -3):

See the `setActiveTab` method of a tabPanel, which accepts either a string (id of the tab element) or an integer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not talking about a tabPanel.  I'm talking about the tab index for navigating through a page with the "tab" button.

Comment: So sorry ;)
I would answer like J.Barrows.